# How to convert a Calendar into the DD-Mon-YY format and weird query results

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have an sql database which has dates in this format ex: 21-JAN-07 and I am creating a query in Java using the Calendar element, however I can't seem to find a function that convert to this format since this doesn't work

```
    DateFormat formatData = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-Mon-YY");
    String dateString= formatData.format(time);
```

I could concatenate my own string, but first I find weird that I can't find a method that does this and also I noticed that when I query manually the database like this

```
 SELECT Technical_Key FROM DIM_CUSTOMER WHERE '01-JAN-99' <= VERSION_START ORDER BY VERSION_START DESC
```

It's returning me rows with VERSION_START earlier than '01-JAN-99' for example 07-JAN-07. So I am not entirely sure whats' going on

Comment: Are you sure `99` is `1999` not `2099`?

Comment: Please read the documentation of a class before using it.

Comment: Why are the dates not stored in a DATETIME field in the database to start with? If they *are*, why are you formatting into a string rather than just using a prepared statement?

Comment: It's in Date format and I am using it in a string because I am forced to use a library where it works this way.

Comment: If it is stored as an Oracle DATE type, you should rewrite your query so it doesn't rely on the default date format for your database. For instance, use an Oracle [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm): `WHERE date '1999-01-01' <= VERSION_START`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`D` is day of year. Use `d`(day of month) which you need. 
And, `Y` is week year. Use `y` (year). For desired output your pattern should be

```
DateFormat formatData = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

For details, Go through this Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: +1 also `MMM` is the month as three letters not `Mon`

Comment: Dooh of course, that's why it's not good to pull an all-nighter, my brain is not working properly right now.